# Is it possible to use System.Net.Mail in a Windows App?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I was surprised to not find `System.Net.Mail` in my Windows App. Is there any way I can use/import that namespace or the SmtpClient class in my Windows App project?

Comment: Is it for Windows Forms App or Console App or Store Apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. System.Net.Mail is not available in Windows Store apps. Windows.Store apps can use only the parts of the .Net Framework available in the [.Net Framework for Windows Store apps](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=238312).

Windows Store apps do not have an explicit email API. In most cases you are better off letting the user choose how to share data rather than hard-coding email. For that you can support the sharing contract.

For many other cases (especially feedback forms) you may better off connecting to a dedicated web service rather than detouring through email.

If you do specifically need email then you can launch a mailto: URI.

And if you're writing an email client and specifically need to connect to the mail server then there isn't anything in box so you'll either need to connect to a service specific API (many modern mail services support REST clients) or implement SMTP yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I need to implement SMTP myself, then … :(